# What would be the correct URI for an endpoint that shares a file with other users?

Tags: api, http

I've been reading through the best practices when it comes to API definitions and one of the most common recommendations is to make sure that your endpoint definitions do not contain verbs in the path (only nouns should be used for the resources as well as values for path parameters). Instead, the HTTP methods should be used as the "verbs" to perform actions over the resources.

The thing is, suppose I want to create an endpoint that allows a user to share a file with other users. The way I would do it would be as follows:

```
POST /api/file/{file_id}/share/
```

With a request body that would look as follows

```
{ users: [1, 2, ... , N] }
```

For me this is the most intuitive way to do it since I am performing an operation over the file resource but none of the HTTP methods is enough to describe the operation and I am forced to use the /share/ in order to be able to specify the action to perform.

I am thus violating the best practices of only using nouns in the endpoint path but I dont see any other possible way to do it except adding query parameters, but those are usually done for filters, sorting, etc.

What would be an adequate way of defining such endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is OK. You can take `/share` as the sub-resource of `/api/file/{file_id}` -- the sharing status of specific file.

So, to share a (not shared yet) file with other users:

`POST /api/file/{file_id}/share`

And to change the user list that file shared with:

`PUT /api/file/{file_id}/share`

To me, `/share` is a good choice -- it's concise and descriptive. However, if you really want to use a noun instead of verb, you can use `/sharing` or `/share-status` etc.